# How to know when a transaction scheme is serializable?

Tags: sql, transactions

I'm studying SQL and need to know whether a certain transaction scheme is serializable. I understand the method of determining this is making a graph with the transactions as nodes and direction between the nodes and if the graph is cyclic then the scheme is not serializable. But what does it mean and what determines whether there is a directed edge in the graph from one transaction to the other? Is serialization in this case the same kind of serialization as writing objects to disk?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transaction serialization has nothing to do with object serialization.  The serializable transaction isolation level, when fully implemented, ensures that the behavior of any set of concurrent serializable transactions is consistent with *some* serial (one-at-a-time) sequence of execution -- as though the transactions had been run one at a time.  This means that if you can show that a database transaction will do the right thing when it is run alone, it will do the right thing in any mix of serializable transactions, or it will roll back with a serialization failure so that it can be retried from the start.

Serializable transaction isolation can be enforced in many ways.  The most common scheme is strict two-phase locking (S2PL).  This one is so common that you often see answers on SO which discuss things only in terms of this technique.  There are also optimistic concurrency control (OCC), serializable snapshot isolation (SSI), and others.

PostgreSQL versions before 9.1, MS SQL Server in some configurations, and all versions of Oracle don't actually provide serializable transactions.  They let you ask for them, but actually provide snapshot isolation.  PostgreSQL versions starting with 9.1 use [SSI](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI) when serializable transaction isolation is requested.

It's not possible to thoroughly discuss how any of these techniques work in an SO answer, but to summarize the techniques mentioned above:

- Under S2PL every write within a transaction acquires a lock which cannot be shared with anything, and every read within the transaction acquires a lock which can be shared with other reads but can not be shared with a write.  The read locks need to cover "gaps" in scanned indexes.  Locks are held until the end of the transaction and released atomically with the work of the transaction becoming visible to other transactions.  If the blocking creates a cycle, this is called a "deadlock", and one of the transactions involved in the cycle is rolled back.
- Under OCC a transaction keeps track of what data it has used, without locking it.  When transaction commit is requested, the transaction checks whether any other transaction modified any of its data and committed.  If so, the commit request fails and the work is rolled back.
- Under SSI writes block each other, but reads don't block writes and writes don't block reads.  There is tracking of read-write dependencies to look for patterns of visibility which would create a cycle in the apparent order of execution.  If a "dangerous structure" is found, which means that a cycle in the apparent order of execution is possible, one of the transactions involved in the possible cycle is rolled back.  It is more like OCC than S2PL, but doesn't have as many rollbacks under higher contention.

Full disclosure: I teamed with Dan R.K. Ports of MIT to implement the new SSI-based serializable transactions in PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I've also learnt how to draw a precedence scheme and that checking whether a scheme is serializable is O(n²) where n is the number of node in the precedence graph. I'm about to check how twophase locking works now on my examples and will continue my studies of B+ trees and transaction.

Comment: SSI avoids the worst performance issues by only looking for two or three transactions which are adjacent in the graph with certain properties. It has been proven that any graph with a cycle will contain this particular "dangerous structure", and checking for it is far cheaper than doing a rigorous check for cycles. See the doctoral thesis of Michael J. Cahill and its referenced works for details. http://hdl.handle.net/2123/5353

Answer (score 2):

Serialization means that transaction can be executed in a serial way, one after the other (nothing to do with object serialization), basically a transaction its serializable if regardless of the order these are interleaved the result will be as if they were executed in a serial way, if the graph its cyclic then it is not serializable and there is some risk of conflict, here is where your isolation level will help to decide wheter the transaction should be executed in a serial way, meaning first one and then the other or wheter it should try to execute it in an interleaved way hoping there is no conflicts.
Its not a complete answer but i hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found this page helpful too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precedence_graph If there is a cycle in the precedence graph, the scheme is not serializable.