# How do databases maintain results if another query edits those results

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, relational-database, mariadb

I was just wondering how most relational databases handled maintaining your set of results if another query has edited those rows that you were working on. For instance if I do a `select` of like 100k rows and while I am still fetching those another query comes in and does an `update` on 1 of the rows that hasn't been read yet the `update` is not going to be seen in the fetching of those rows and I was wondering how the database engine handles that. If you only have specifics for one type of database thats fine I would like to hear it anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database: What is Multiversion Concurrency Control (MVCC) and who supports it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499/database-what-is-multiversion-concurrency-control-mvcc-and-who-supports-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please lookup Multi Version Concurrency Control. Different databases have different approaches to managing this. For MySQL, InnoDB, you can try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html. PostgreSQL - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MVCC. A great presentation here - http://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/mvcc.pdf. It is explained in stackoverflow in this thread [Database: What is Multiversion Concurrency Control (MVCC) and who supports it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499/database-what-is-multiversion-concurrency-control-mvcc-and-who-supports-it)

Answer (score 1):

The general goal you are describing in concurrent programming (Wikipedia [concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control)) is serialization (Wikipedia [serializability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability)): an implementation manages the database as if transactions occurred without overlap in some order.

The importance of that is that only then does the system act in a way described by the code as we normally interpret it. Otherwise the results of operations are a combination of all processes acting concurrently. Nevertheless by having limited categories of non-normal non-isolated so-called anomalous behaviours arise transaction throughput can be increased. So those implementation techniques are also apropos. (Eg MVCC.) But understand: such non-serialized behaviour is *not* isolating one transaction from another. (Ie so-called "isolation" levels are actually non-isolation levels.)

Isolation is managed by breaking transaction implementations into pieces based on reading and writing shared resources and executing them interlaced with pieces from other transactions in such a way that the effect is the same as some sequence of non-overlapped execution. Roughly speaking, one can "pessimistically" "lock" out other processes from changed resources and have them wait or "optimistically" "version" the database and "roll back" (throw away) some processes' work when changes are unreconcilable (unserializable).

Some techniques based on an understanding of serializability by an implementer for a  major product are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550750/3404097). For relevant notions and techniques, see the Wikipedia articles or a database textbook. Eg Fundamentals of database systems by Ramez Elmasri & Shamkant B. Navathe. (Many textbooks, slides and courses are free online.)

(Two answers and a comment to your question mention MVCC. As I commented, not only is MVCC just one implementation technique, it doesn't even support transaction serialization, ie actually isolating transactions as if each was done all at once. It allows certain kinds of errors (aka anomalies). It must be mixed with other techniques for isolation. The MVCC answers, comments and upvoting reflects a confusion between a popular and valuable technique for a useful and limited *failure* to isolate per your question vs the actual core issues and means.)

Answer (score 0):

As Jayadevan notes, the general principle used by *most widely used* databases that permit you to modify values while they're being read is [multi-version concurrency control or MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). All *widely used modern RDBMS* implementations that support reading rows that're being updated rely on some concept of row versioning.

The details differ between implementations. (I'll explain PostgreSQL's a little more here, but you should accept Jayadevan's answer not mine).

[PostgreSQL uses transaction ID ranges to track row visibility](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc.html). So there'll be multiple copies of a tuple in a table, but any given transaction can only "see" one of them. Each transaction has a unique ID, with newer transactions having newer IDs. Each tuple has hidden `xmin` and `xmax` fields that track which transactions can "see" the tuple. Insertion is implimented by setting the tuple's `xmin` so that transactions with lower xids know to ignore the tuple when reading the table. Deletion is implimented by setting the tuple's `xmax` so that transactions with higher xids know to ignore the tuple when reading the table. Updates are implemented by effectively deleting the old tuple (setting `xmax`) then inserting a new one (setting `xmin`) so that old transactions still see the old tuple, but new transactions see the new tuple. When no running transaction can still see a deleted tuple, `vacuum` marks it as free space to be overwritten.

Oracle uses undo and redo logs, so there's only one copy of the tuple in the main table, and transactions that want to find old versions have to go and find it in the logs. Like PostgreSQL it uses row versioning, though I'm less sure of the details.

Pretty much every other DB uses a similar approach these days. Those that used to rely on locking, like older MS-SQL versions, have moved to MVCC.

MySQL uses MVCC with InnoDB tables, which are now the default. MyISAM tables still rely on table locking (but they'll also eat your data, so don't use them for anything you care about).

A few embedded DBs, like SQLite, still rely only on table locking - which tends to require less wasted disk space and I/O overhead, at the cost of greatly reduced concurrency. Some databases let you bypass MVCC if you take an exclusive lock on a table.

(Marked community wiki, since I also close-voted this question).

You should also read the PostgreSQL docs on [transaction isolation](http://explain.depesz.com/s/bzz4) and [locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html), and similar documentation for other DBs you use. See the Wikipedia article on [isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)).

Comment: MVCC is definitely *not* "the general principle", see my comment on the question.

Comment: @philipxy Sure, there's more involved - once you start covering the transaction rollback log, isolation levels, locking, predicate locking and pivots (per `SERIALIZABLE` in PostgreSQL) etc you rapidly get into "I'm writing a book" territory. *For the majority of DB systems* MVCC is now a large part of what makes read/write concurrency possible. That said, I'll certainly add a link to Pg's docs on transaction isolation, which provide some more info.

Comment: It is simply wrong to call MVCC the general principle and wrong to say it achieves isolation per the user's question. MVCC is in no way a core around which to form an understanding of the issue.  Framing an answer around it fundamentally misrepresents the issues. Your comment further illustrates this: rollback logs and durability are orthogonal to isolation; "isolation" [sic] levels are all about (again) *non*-isolation; and levels & MVCC make higher *throughput* possible, not concurrency. Agree that @legion should read a book. Agree it's a relevant (limited) technique.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you were to follow up with an answer discussing the topic as you think it needs to be covered; I think it's a bit much for comment chat. Or, if you prefer, feel free to amend the CW one above to your satisfaction.

Comment: Agree. It was in the works. If I get a chance I will add detail to my "roughly speaking".

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot isolation solves the problem you are describing. If you use locking, you can see the same record twice as the iterator through the database, as the unlocked records change underneath your feet as you're doing the scan.

[Read committed isolation level with locking suffers from this problem](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-committed-isolation-level).

Depending on the granularity of the lock, the WHERE predicate may lock matching pages and tuples for locking so that the running read query doesn't see phantom data appearing (phantom reads)

I implemented [multiversion concurrency control in my Java project](https://github.com/samsquire/multiversion-concurrency-control). A transaction is given a monotonically increasing timestamp which starts at 0 and goes up by 1 each time the transaction is aborted. Later transactions have higher timestamps. When a transaction goes to read, it can only see data that has a timestamp that is less than or equal to itself and is committed for that key (or column of that tuple). (Equal to so it can see its own writes)

When a transaction writes, it updates the committed timestamp for that key to that of that transactions timestamp.